# PHP JSON Parsing

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am a newbie and have an issue in parsing json.

Below is the json array I want to parse:

```
 array (size=3)
  'status' => string 'success' (length=7)
  'message' => string '' (length=0)
  'data' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'asset' => string 'ONESATOSHI' (length=10)
          'balance' => string '0.0000001' (length=9)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'asset' => string 'XCP' (length=3)
          'balance' => string '150333.69737005' (length=15)
```

I want to get the balance of array 1.

I have tried this:

```
function xcp_balance($wallet)
{   
    $jarr = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://xcp.blockscan.com/api2.aspx?module=address&action=balance&btc_address='.$wallet),true);

    $balance = $jarr['data'][1]['balance'];

    if (is_numeric($balance)) {
        return $balance;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}

$wallet = '1NFeBp9s5aQ1iZ26uWyiK2AYUXHxs7bFmB';
xcp_balance($wallet);
```

But it not working. Kindly help me and apologies for my language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its working. You just forgot to echo the returned value:

```
function xcp_balance($wallet) {

    $jarr = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://xcp.blockscan.com/api2.aspx?module=address&action=balance&btc_address='.$wallet),true);
    $balance = $jarr['data'][1]['balance'];

    if (is_numeric($balance)) {
        return $balance;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}

$wallet = '1NFeBp9s5aQ1iZ26uWyiK2AYUXHxs7bFmB';
echo xcp_balance($wallet); // 150333.69737005
// ^ echo it
```

[Working here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QRDgUL)

And it might be better to check the existence of that index first:

```
function xcp_balance($wallet) {

    $jarr = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://xcp.blockscan.com/api2.aspx?module=address&action=balance&btc_address='.$wallet),true);
    $balance = (isset($jarr['data'][1]['balance']) && is_numeric($jarr['data'][1]['balance']) ? $jarr['data'][1]['balance'] : 0);

    return $balance;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot sir!You have saved me from alot of headache.My Warm Regards to you.

Comment: @user2507910 sure no prob. im glad this helped